# Rest Api not found in django application

Tags: django

I'm trying to do a simple app in django, I'm a beginner and I'm having some problems;

My error is: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
My view:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        users = [
            {'id': 1, 'name': 'John', 'phone': '3382496345','email': 'john@example.com'},
            {'id': 2, 'name': 'Jane', 'phone': '3382496345','email': 'jane@example.com'},
        ]
        serializer = self.serializer_class(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('users',UserViewSet.as_view({'get':'users'}), basename='user')
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

I don'know wher is my error

I tried this also:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
      path('api/users/', UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
]
```

but I receive this error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Christian\Documents\VS_projects\python\gestionale\users\views.py", line 17, in list      
    return Response(serializer.data)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
[12/Sep/2023 00:42:20] "GET /api/users/ HTTP/1.1" 500 93677
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.as_view` should define a mapping from a HTTP method to a function name, so here `list`, not `users`, so `UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})`.

But more importantly: you don't use the result of an `.as_view()`, a function thus, in a router. The idea of a router is to call a function based on a certain path. That is something you seem to do with the `.as_view()`, so you either pass a reference to the `ViewSet`, or you register the `.as_view()` as a target of a path, so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/users/', UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
]
```

Comment: now my error is: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @ChristianTermo: can you edit the question with the full traceback?

Comment: @ChristianTermo: you likely imported the wrong `Response` class, or defined one yourself. You should use the `Response` provided by the `django_rest` package.

Comment: I can't find this package, I have to install it?

Comment: @ChristianTermo: sorry, I mean from `rest_framework.response import Response`